# Rendering problems for some polygons in a Leaflet map with a GeoJSON tile provider

Tags: leaflet, geojson, vector-tiles

New to mapping.

Trying to create a heat map with data that updates every hour for US Counties with leaflet.js similar to http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/examples/choropleth-example.html.  But, adding all the US Counties in 1 shot makes map jerky in IE.

So found this example of using GeoJSON tiles with leaflet.js, http://bl.ocks.org/3725681

Only problem is that many tiles are not rendered completely.  I think some of the z/x/y.json files are missing coordinates, but not sure.  Can someone point me to the right direction of the problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That gist is using GeoJSON designed for [polymaps](http://polymaps.org/). While polymaps handled it correctly ([see the original example](http://polymaps.org/ex/statehood.html)), this Leaflet code (not Leaflet itself, the GeoJSON tiled layer connector) isn't quite complete.

So, part of this is that it's not quite finished. But the more-big part is that things being 'jerky' in IE is the norm - IE is a very bad web browser, and older versions will not handle vector rendering well regardless how much development time is put into projects.

Answer (score 2):

this little piece of code might be just what you need:
https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson

Comment: yep this version is a more up to date version of the gist at http://bl.ocks.org/3725681.